# Change mysql storage engine from Innodb to MyIsam: Max locks exceeded error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have about 5 million records in a table which uses Innodb as storage engine. I have about 6000 users who use (do transactions) the same table. It sometimes becomes very slow or hangs. I decided to manually change to MyIsam. When I try to copy to another table and change the storage engine in phpmyadmin, it gives me `Max Locks Exceeded Error`. What should I do?

Comment: IT's not quite clear whether you try to change the engine of the original table or that of the copy.  However, I think you should first disconnect all the other connections (and don't let users reconnect until you finish).

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simply to edit my.cnf, and add or edit the following line:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
```

To make it work, I set the size in bytes, so if I wanted 256 megabytes for my buffer pool, I would write 268435456. It would look like like this thus:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 268435456
```